# Calculating web page engagement duration from GA4 event data in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to be able to calculate the engagement time for a given user on a given page. Historically we've used the API data segmented by page and user_id (custom field) dimensions and the userEngagementDuration metric but believe it may be more accurate to use event data.

For arcane reasons (which cannot easily be solved) the API data for our app cannot be used so the event data may also provide an alternate route to get this data.

My understanding is that Google build this metric from the engagement_time_msec parameter, and drawing on [this](https://firebase.blog/posts/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement/) I've written the following SQL

```
SELECT
  custom_user_id,
  page_location,
  SUM(engagement_time)/1000 AS total_engagagement_time
FROM
(

SELECT 
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'custom_user_id') AS custom_user_id,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = "engagement_time_msec") AS engagement_time,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'user_status') AS user_status
FROM 
  `my_GBQ_event_table`
)
WHERE
  user_status = 'subscriber'
GROUP BY
  custom_user_id,
  page_location
ORDER BY
  custom_user_id, 
  total_engagagement_time DESC
```

(Please don't critique the SQL stylistically - this is more a prototype!)

The issue I have is that the data that I get from this query - when I spot check against data from the GA4 API - doesn't necessarily match. Typically this gives a longer - but not implausible engagement time. Does this SQL query seem to be fundamentally correct in its assumptions? - I could imagine that the API data is not necessarily "perfect" due to sampling or other issues, so it's not clear what "truth" is!